# How to call JS function before HTML load completed?

Tags: javascript, html

I write a JS function to hide some elements in HTML and use `window.onload()` to call this function. But there is a problem that `window.onload()` call functions after HTML load completed, which makes those elements display in the webpage first and wait a few seconds they disappeared. So do I have some methods to make it be hidden at the beginning in loading process of this webpage?

Here is my JS code:

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    e.style.display = 'none';
}

window.onload = function () {
    toggle_visibility("excelDataTable_epgd");
    toggle_visibility("EPGD_SIZE");
}
```

Comment: `onload` will wait for the whole page, including linked resources like images, to be loaded. Use [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) to trigger as soon as HTML is loaded. If you need to be more precise, put a `<script>` element immediately after each element. But all that ignores the burning question: why not just hide the elements from the start directly by CSS?

Answer (score 3):

How about you make the default visibility none first and then enable the ones you want to display after page load?

Comment: You don't have to be afraid of using complete words. The character limit for answers is pretty high. Please use proper English words, e.g. "you" instead of "u". Thank you!

Comment: I think "U" understood what he was trying to say. This is a technical Q&A forum, not an English language correction platform. :)

Comment: @Chris: Of course I can. But I also want people to understand and learn.

Comment: @FelixKling This is what I get for trying to answer a question while laying in bed, typing with one hand only. Otherwise I'd have used proper grammar.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that if you want to hide the elements in the first place on page load, you do it directly *(either by external or on the fly)*.

**E.g.**

```js
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    var display = e.style.display;
    if (display == 'none') {
       e.style.display = 'block';
    }
    else {
       e.style.display = 'none';
    }
}

window.onload = function () {
    toggle_visibility("excelDataTable_epgd");
    toggle_visibility("EPGD_SIZE");
}
```

```html
       <div id="excelDataTable_epgd" style="display: none"> </div>
        <div id="EPGD_SIZE" style="display: none"> </div>
```

Then, on page finishes loading, you can run your JS function to make them visible.

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    var display = e.style.display;
    if (display == 'none') {
       e.style.display = 'block';
    }
    else {
       e.style.display = 'none';
    }
}

window.onload = function () {
    toggle_visibility("excelDataTable_epgd");
    toggle_visibility("EPGD_SIZE");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, the best way would be to initially hide the element via CSS, since that wouldn't cause the browser to redraw.

But more generally speaking, the fastest way to manipulate a DOM element via JS is to put the code directly after the element.

E.g.

```
<div id="foo">...</div>
<script>toggle_visibility('foo')</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before the HTML load completed, HTML elements have not yet joined the DOM tree, call JS function is unable to operate a DOM element, so you need to use CSS to hide the elements, and then call JS function makes the element display.